# WooCommerce | Display product attributes between Title and Add to cart button on product page

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product

How to display product attributes between Title and Add to cart button on product page in WooCommerce?

Id like it to be placed in the description zone right after product Title or just before Add to cart button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYu3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Good evening. Im not an expert but if you know the slug of the attribute you can get it with the function `get_attributes` and place them wherever you want with a `hook`. In this case the attribute is "pa_cantidad" and his values are (1,5,10 Piezas from a total of 1,2,3,5,10,100 Piezas), so it could be like this:

***EDIT***: It may need a little bit of more code if you want the attributes to be "linkeable". Also you must go to your Attribute Settings and activate the option of "***Enable Archive attributes - Enable this if you want this attribute to have product archives in your store.***", without that this code will not work https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcTTI.jpg

```
function atributos()
{
    global $product,$post;
    echo "Atributos :";

$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute )
        {  
          $attribute_name = $attribute['name'];//pa_cantidad

        }
        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute_name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

        foreach( $terms as $term ){

        $Atributo=$term->name;
        $slug=$term->slug;
        $site_url=get_site_url();//http://localhost/psa
        $tax=substr($attribute_name,3);
        echo " <a href=".$site_url."/".$tax."/".$slug.">".$Atributo."</a> ";
        }
}    
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'atributos', 5 );
```

It works and this is how it looks now in my Storefront Theme. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t92Bx.jpg

If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah it works, but is it possible to add a link to those attributes? For example 1,5,10 Piezas will have link to attribute page.

Comment: You need to specify that in your question. I have updated my answer. i tested it and it works. If my answer helped you, please mark it as an answer.